# How do I layer the text box hint in a Flutter text book like in the mock below?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, mobile, frontend

I'm working on my onboarding screens for a Flutter mobile app I'm developing, and I want to make my textboxes look like the mock here below:
[The desired goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Qyx.png)

I have already created most of the text box, but I can't figure out how to make the hint move to the top of the textbox whenever there is text entered in the box. So far I have the below representation does anyone have a clue on how I could do that?
[My current implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw06l.png)

Comment: Please include some sample code @Earl Potts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do it by**

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'Full Name',
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Samples:**

[image: When Text Field is focused]

[image: When Text Field is not focused]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. What you want is called `labelText` with `floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto`

Example

```
    TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Username *",
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))
                ),
            )
          )
```